# Cordova - Android 4 - Google Map JS

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps

I use Cordova to build an App that use Google Map, in my html file I import this file:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&libraries=places&language=en
```

When I build the app with Cordova, on iOS and Android with version >= 5 all works good, instead on Android v4 I can't see the map, I see an empty div where the map should, and I doesn't know what goes wrong. Anyone know if there is something special to do for this Android version?

Comment: Did you check if your project includes the whitelist plugin and that it is properly configured (whitelisting the maps urls) through a meta tag in the index.html?

Comment: yes I use it, I don't know if it's properly configured. But that not explain why on Android 5 or 6 works well, right?